# Additional Params in 'GET' request of localbitcoins API

Tags: api, http, url, get, request

LocalBitcoins API I'm using '[Documentation Link](https://localbitcoins.com/api-docs/#trades)'

Route is: '/bitcoincharts/{currency}/trades.json'

this is the route which gives you 500 data items

```
https://localbitcoins.com/bitcoincharts/USD/trades.json
```

i want more than 500 data items, by adding 'Optional arguments  max_tid'

How can i add this param in GET request?

Answer (score 1):

You can't get more than 500 data items. You can get only older data items. For example:
You get answer with latest 500 items. Tid for latest items is 4000. If you send new request with 'max_rid':4000 you will get response with older data items. 
`params = {'max_tid': 41719737}
value = conn_no.call('GET', '/bitcoincharts/uah/trades.json' , params = params).json()`